# Why are two questions which are very similar except for the sect/deity concerned treated differently?

Tags: support

[Who are the most important acharyas of the Gaudiya sect?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/55902/who-are-the-most-important-acharyas-of-the-gaudiya-sect)

is very similar to

[What is the most important text of Saiva sect?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/55896/what-is-the-most-important-text-of-saiva-sect)

The second question was **downvoted and closed**

How is this within HSE code of conduct?

Comment: "Which is the most important scripture for Shaivism?" is definitely opinion based .. but "name some important scriptures of Shaivism" is probably not .. I think that is the reason.

Comment: Also about the downvotes I can't comment as I have not downvoted .. but the question is definitely opinion based .. moreover the question is asking about something but accepted an answer that is talking about something else .. Sri Rudram is not a text, its a collection of Mantras for Lord Shiva found In Yajurveda. Same for Sri Chandi, it is not a text but a collection of 700 mantras found in Markandeya Puran.. so there can be some reasons users might have downvoted. The other question on the other hand is clear and not based on any wrong premise.

Comment: you can close if you feel first question is opinion based too.. maybe users didn't observe and vote it..

Answer (score -3):

The closure of this question is hard to understand.

this question

[How important is the Bhagavad Gita when compared to other Hindu texts?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15924/how-important-is-the-bhagavad-gita-when-compared-to-other-hindu-texts)

is as "opinion based" as they come - and has been sitting there for 6 years, unchallenged.

Participants put a lot of effort into posts and should be given the benefit of the doubt when it comes to their content being judged as "opinion based", which has some subjectivity to it.

Comment: "s as "opinion based" as they come" --- Yes that one is opinion based and there can be many reasons why it has not been closed .. it was asked way back ... if it was asked today it would have been closed .. over hype over Gita may be another reason users did not want to close it .. lastly many users might have close voted it but their votes aged away .. also your argument "since that question is not closed no other similar questions should be closed too" does not work.

Comment: I agree with Rickross, basically it is an opinion, but a popular one. Lay people are easily fooled by fallacies—in recent decades, the popularity fallacy in particular.